# Message not being tranfered to other chat but the reaction counts on console

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I would like to transfer an embed message to another chat with reactions, but I'm having some troubles because the BOT isn't tranferying the message with this code:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if (message.channel.id === analiseChannelID) {
        message.react(aprovada);
        message.react(nula);
        message.react(negada);
    } else if (message.channel.id === aprovadasChannelID) {
        message.react(arquivada);
        message.react(negada);
    } else if (message.channel.id === negadasChannelID) {
        message.react(arquivada);
        message.react(negada);
    } else if (message.channel.id === nulaChannelID) {
        message.react(arquivada);
        message.react(negada);
    }
});

client.on("messageReactionAdd", ({ message }) => {
    const analiseChannel = message.client.channels.cache.get(analiseChannelID);
    const aprovadasChannel = message.client.channels.cache.get(aprovadasChannelID);

    console.log("Reaction");

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.guild.channels.id = analiseChannelID) {
        const { embeds } = message
        aprovadasChannel.send({
            embeds
        })
    }
});
```

When I added this to not let him take his own reaction and spam the chat:

```js
    if (message.author.bot) return;
```

he just ignore to transfer the message.

> What I have to do is if there is a new embed on `analiseChannelID`, he should react with 3 emojis, and deppending on those reactions, he would transfer the message to `aprovadasChannelID` and delete from `analiseChannelID`

Comment: Who's message is being reacted to?

Comment: He is reacting to an embed message sended by a discord hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69807540/message-not-being-tranfered-to-other-chat-but-the-reaction-counts-on-console?noredirect=1#comment123401912_69807540), you sent the message as a Discord webhook. Webhooks are classified as bot messages. If you were trying to get the user who reacted, you can use the second argument of the [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) event. It's a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object which represents the user who reacted.

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", ({ message }, user) => { //get the User who reacted
    const analiseChannel = message.client.channels.cache.get(analiseChannelID);
    const aprovadasChannel = message.client.channels.cache.get(aprovadasChannelID);

    console.log("Reaction");

    if (user.bot) return;

    if (message.guild.channels.id = analiseChannelID) {
        const { embeds } = message
        aprovadasChannel.send({
            embeds
        })
    }
});
```

Note there are more mistakes in the code

- the if statement's condition is not put in correctly. It must be either `==` or `===`
- `message.guild.channels.id` is undefined. If you would like to check if a channel exists, which is what I think you are doing, use `message.guild.channels.cache.has("ID")`

Comment: So this part here `const analiseChannel = message.client.channels.cache.get(analiseChannelID);` ​isn't really needed, right?

And how should it filter the reaction on that specific channel? Because that way he will execute the code every time a reaction on that guilt is used, regardless of what reaction it is and chat.

Comment: `if (message.channel.id !== "the channel id that you want to allow") return;`

Comment: To reactions, why doesn't it works like channels? I've tried like this `if (reaction.emoji.id == aprovada) { /* code */ }` inside the channel if, and tried the something like on [https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#awaiting-reactions] discord.js doc

Answer (score 0):

Guess the problem is here:

```js
if (message.guild.channels.id = analiseChannelID)
```

What you're doing by using the single '=' operator is assigning the `analiseChannelID` value to `message.guild.channels.id`(which doesn't even exists since guild.channels is a channel manager) and then checking if the value assigned is not a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value for javascript. Unfortunately your question isn't very clear about what you're trying to achieve, but i guess what you want to do instead is something like:

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", ({ message }) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    const analiseChannel = message.client.channels.resolve(analiseChannelID);
    const aprovadasChannel = message.client.channels.resolve(aprovadasChannelID);

    // you can use the has method since the cache is a Collection instance
    // this if you want to check if the guild has a channel with that id
    if (message.guild.channels.cache.has(analiseChannelID)) {
        const { embeds } = message;
        aprovadasChannel.send({
            embeds
        });
    }
    // this if you want to ckeck if the channel in which the message has been sent is that channel id
    if(message.channel.id === analiseChannelID) { /* do stuff */ }
});
```